# Krusader: Use quick filter instead of quick search by default

Tags: kde

In the Krusader file manager, I need to press Ctrl+I to invoke quick filter. If I just start typing, the quick search function is used instead. Is it possible to change the default, so quick filter is always used instead of quick search, without needing to press Ctrl+I first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for reviving this old thread, i dont usually tends to perform necromancy, but maybe this will be of some help :-)

You can set this up by going **Settings > Configure Krusader > Panel > Search bar** and there you just switch **Default mode** to **Filter**.

This works for Krusader v2.7.1.